# display:none does not work for label

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 ways of text input for the user - through an input text field, or by choosing a predefined text from a dropdown menu. Javascript controls which one is visible.
So I have those 2 input methods and their corresponding 2 labels:

```
<h:form id="test">
<div>
  <h:outputLabel id="label_1" value="Your text:" style="display:block" />
  <h:inputText id="txt" value="#{myform.inputText}" style="display:block" />

  <h:outputLabel id="label_2" value="Choose text:" style="display:none" />
  <h:selectOneMenu id="drop" value="#{myform.inputText}" style="display:none">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="11" itemLabel="Preselected text 1" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="22" itemLabel="Preselected text 2" />
  </h:selectOneMenu>
</div>
</h:form>
```

The javascript shows and hides the elements:

```
if (...) {
  document.getElementById('label_1').style.display="none";
  document.getElementById('txt').style.display="none";
  document.getElementById('label_2').style.display="block";
  document.getElementById('drop').style.display="block";
}
else {
  document.getElementById('label_1').style.display="block";
  document.getElementById('txt').style.display="block";
  document.getElementById('label_2').style.display="none";
  document.getElementById('drop').style.display="none";
}
```

So, it's either **label_1 + txt** or **label_2 + drop**
Here is the problem: when the page loads, only **label_1 + txt** should be visible. Unfortunately, label_1, **label_2** and txt are visible!

Why is drop's definition style="display:none" working and label_2's same definition is not?

Comment: Did you check whether your JavaScript gets executed/there is a JavaScript error on your page? Could you provide a [short, self-contained example](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: What kind of markup is that?

Comment: There must be your code error. check it by typing directly `document.getElementById('label_2').style.display="none";` on your console.

Comment: but that's the problem - the code if .. else .. works! I can really see only one label when I start using the page. Just at the beginning, I can see both labels.

Comment: The default display for select elements is inline-block, the default for labels is inline. Far better to toggle between "none" and "" (empty string) so that when not "none", elements adopt their default or cascaded display value.

Comment: What is rendered to the page? View the source, is that serverside markup dumping your style tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add a jQuery block in a script in the body

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id$=label_2]').hide();
    $('[id$=drop]').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hide label**

```
function Hide(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";
}​

Hide('label_1');
```

**Show label**

```
function Show(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";
}

Show('label_1');
```

Comment: I tried with `<h:outputLabel id="label_2" value="Choose text:" style="visibility:hidden" />` but the label_2 is still being shown at the beginning.

Comment: Is the `outputLabel` related to `salesforce` or `jsf` ?

Comment: visibility and display are two different beasts.